# How to do custom binding of listview datasource in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview

I have a list view data source which gets the data from the table, which has roleId, first name, last name, mobile number.
I have another table that maps roleId with the role Name.

In the asp.net form, I have bound the datasource to the table which retrieves the roleId,firstname, and last name. I am using backend programming to do so.

My question is, how can I display rolename instead of roleid in the listview.

My backend code is like this

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!this.IsPostBack)
    {
        this.BindListView();
    }
}

private void BindListView()
{
    string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constr"].ConnectionString;
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
        {
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT roleId, fName, lname,mobilenumber Country FROM Admin";
            cmd.Connection = con;
            using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
            {
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                sda.Fill(dt);
                lvCustomers.DataSource = dt;
                lvCustomers.DataBind();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Obviously,this returns integer roleId and now I want to display role name rather than roleId. I can get rolename from roletable which maps roleID with rolename.

Answer (score 0):

Use inner join in your SQL as below. This is a simple fix than updating the DataTable after fetching data.

"SELECT roleName, fName, lname,mobilenumber Country FROM Admin A Inner join RoleTable R on A.roleID = R.roleID";

Comment: If you are allowed use LINQ. You can try something like this                                                                      var results = from table1 in dt1.AsEnumerable()
                 join table2 in dt2.AsEnumerable() on (int)table1["CustID"] equals (int)table2["CustID"]
                 select new
                 {
                     CustID = (int)table1["CustID"],
                     ColX = (int)table1["ColX"],
                     ColY = (int)table1["ColY"],
                     ColZ = (int)table2["ColZ"]
                 };